# Junit and mockito with spring boot list is not available

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spring-test

hi every one i have some problem

i have a test class called `TestUserService`

```java
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class TestUserService {
    
        @InjectMocks
        UserService userService;
    
        @Mock
        InMemory inMemory;
    
    
    
    
        @Before
        public void init(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
    
        @Test
        public void registry(){
            
            System.out.println("hi");
            UserDto userDto=new UserDto(1L,"abed","alrhman",26);
            UserDto userDto1=new UserDto(1L,"abdallah","almasre",27);
            UserDto userDto2=new UserDto(1L,"bisher","alahmad",35);
            UserDto userDto3=new UserDto(1L,"ibrahem","alrabe",32);
    
           
            userService.registry(userDto);
            userService.registry(userDto1);
            userService.registry(userDto2);
            userService.registry(userDto3);
            System.out.println("\"registry\" = " + "registry");
            verify(inMemory,times(0)).save(userDto.ToDTO(userDto));
            verify(inMemory,times(1)).save(userDto1.ToDTO(userDto1));
            verify(inMemory,times(0)).save(userDto2.ToDTO(userDto2));
            verify(inMemory,times(0)).save(userDto3.ToDTO(userDto3));
    
        }
    
    }
```

when run the test i want save new user by `UserService` class and `UserService` will go to `InMemory` class

```java
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    private final InMemory inMemory;

    public UserService(InMemory inMemory){
        this.inMemory=inMemory;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDto registry(UserDto userDto) {
        User user=userDto.ToDTO(userDto);
        User user1=inMemory.save(user);
        return user.toEntity(user1);
    }
}
```

the problem in `InMemory` Class it is a local repository has Map Called users and some other methods
after called   registry(User user) method
the Map has it when debugger 'this' is not available
and the user param not receive into the `save(User user)` method and the debugger dont walk of any point check

```java
private Map<Long,User> users=new HashMap<>();
    @Override
    public  User save(User user) {
        user.setId(1L);
        users.put(1L,user);
        return user;
    }
```

and this is Image when debugger code

[image]

if you attention `save(User user)` dont has object or any value and users map not avalible

Comment: Ofcourse not it is a mock so it doesn't have (or do) anything.

Comment: i dont understand what do you mean @M.Deinum pleas explain that

Answer (score 1):

In your test, you are defining `InMemory` as a mock. A mock is an object that emulates the behavior of a real object according to how you configure such mock to behave. Having said that, your `InMemory` object in your test is not a real `InMemory` object, but a simple mock which means that its real code will not be called. Take a look at `@Spy` and consider replacing `@Mock` with it. Find more information in the following articles:

- https://medium.com/swlh/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mock-and-a-stub-bd6b639e9fa5
- https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations#mock-annotation

Answer (score 0):

in first step we must replace `@Mock` to `Spy`

and then we must change in  `when()` method to   `when(spyInstance.method)` and then we need called method has `spyInstance.method` to testing

this is my code after fixed you can see it

```
@Spy
InMemory inMemoryGet;  // replace it from mock to spy


@InjectMocks
UserService userService;

@Before
public void init(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void registry(){

    UserDto emp = new UserDto(1L,"Lokesh","Gupta",25); // add it

    when(inMemoryGet.save(emp.ToDTO(emp))).thenReturn(emp.ToDTO(emp));
    verify(inMemoryGet, times(0)).save(emp.ToDTO(emp)); // how many time invoke
    userService.registry(emp); // called method from here
    verify(inMemoryGet, times(1)).save(emp.ToDTO(emp));
    System.out.println("\"Test\" = " + "Pass");
}
```