# test void method using mockito and Junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test

i want test for void method using mockito and junit but after run the test will return exception
`NoSuchElementException`

this code

```
@Spy
InMemory inMemoryGet;


@InjectMocks
UserService userService;

@Test
public void deleteUser(){
    User user=new User(2L,"abed","mohamed",26);
    userService.deleteUser(2L);
    verify(inMemoryGet,times(1)).deleteUser(2L);
}
```

`InMemory` class

```
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
    System.out.println("users = " + users.size());
    users.remove(id,getById(id).get());
    System.out.println("users.size() = " + users.size());

}
```

and `UserService` class

```
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
    inMemory.deleteUser(id);
}
```

work folw for test case
`UserService` executed   `deleteId(id)` method and then called in `deleteId(id)` in `InMemory` class and then `InMemory` completed the process

Note: in this test i don't have database just localdb after close application will delete all data

Comment: You can use anyLong() instead of the long literals for your deleteUser() method.

Comment: Which class are you trying to test?

Comment: i know that but will return the same exception @imprezzeb

Comment: @JoãoDias UserService class

Comment: The why are you calling `inMemoryGet.deleteUser(2L);` and verifying `verify(userService,times(1)).deleteUser(2L);`? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: yes i think use but i am trying many way and i  forget replace it  but we have the same error with two way @JoãoDias

Comment: Can you add both `InMemory` and `UserService` to your question? And also the complete stacktrace? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237695/discussion-between-abdalrhman-alkraien-and-joao-dias).

Comment: @JoãoDias  i  updated the question

Comment: @JoãoDias  i  updated the question

Comment: why a @Spy and not @Mock?

Comment: because i wiche have some problem with ```@Mock```
and the ```@spy ```that soultion of it
you can see the problem from here  @JorgeB
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69376776/junit-and-mockito-with-spring-boot-list-is-not-available/69384270#69384270

Answer (score 1):

You have created 'user' in the test method, not in InMemory class. In other words, the created object 'user' does not exist in the 'users' list in InMemory bean. So during execution of deleteUser(), you see the exception NoSuchElementException. You have to add this object ( User user=new User(2L,"abed","mohamed",26) ) to 'users' List and then try to delete it.